# Golang sub-router alias

Tags: go, mux

I have this right now:

```
    // people
    handler := routes.PersonHandler{}
    subRouter := router.PathPrefix("/person").Subrouter()
    subRouter.Use(authMiddleware)
    handler.Mount(subRouter, routes.PersonInjection{People: models.PersonInit()})
```

I am wonder if there is a way to send both "/person" and "/people" to the same subrouter? Just in need of an alias at the moment.